# googleChartApiPromise with $q.all giving the error "chart type is not defined."

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to use `angular-google-charts` with `$http` service to fetch the data and populate the charts. For that I followed the tutorial from this blog post: http://nicholasbering.ca/angularjs/2015/04/02/google-charts-api-promise/ because github README for `angular-google-charts` don't have examples showing the backend data service.

I'm getting this error:

[image: Chart Not defined]

```
function SomeCtrl(
  $scope,
  $log,
  $stateParams,
  googleChartApiPromise,
  $http,
  $q) {

    googleChartApiPromise.then(function() {

      $scope.goodsAndServicesChartObject = {};

      init();

      function init() {
        var dataPromise = $http.get('businesses/' + $stateParams.businessId + '/contact_users/gender');

        $q.all({
            data: dataPromise,
            api: googleChartApiPromise
          })
          .then(apiLoadSuccess);
      }

      function apiLoadSuccess(result) {
        $scope.goodsAndServicesChartObject.type = 'PieChart';
        $scope.goodsAndServicesChartObject.options = {
          'title': 'Goods Vs Services'
        };
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
        data.addRows(result.data.data);

        $scope.goodsAndServicesChartObject.data = data;

      }
    });
  }
```

Sometimes it loads the image when `googleChartApiPromise` is not `undefined`.

[image: Chart]

I'm wondering why `googleChartApiPromise` get undefined sometimes ?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I asked the repository owner and figured that I forgot to use the `ng-if` to hide the chart if it's not loaded and enable it when data is loaded.

Also we don't have to use `googleChartApiPromise.then` too as it's already being included in the `api: googleChartApiPromise`. Just defining a variable for `ng-if` will correct the problem.

Full Discussion is here: https://github.com/angular-google-chart/angular-google-chart/issues/208